# Windows IOT default app source code

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, iot

I am looking for the source code of the default app on windows IOT that microsoft is using on the raspberry pi 2. There are a few things that i would like to use that is in the default app. Thanks

Comment: Why the down vote with no comment? I am looking at how microsoft updates and installs apps through the default app so that i might add an updater to my app. There is no way to update app since there is no store to update on IOT. So the next logical thing would be manually but i have to see how they do it in order to get an idea on how i can approach the updating. I know i can update the app through the default app or visual studio but i want my app to check and update itself. Also down voting without comment shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: Down voting without commenting is allowed. Anyways, if you check [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you'll see that asking for some off-site resource is not on topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all of the up-to-date samples provided for Windows IoT at: 
https://github.com/ms-iot/samples

Source code of default app is available at:

https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/IoTCoreDefaultApp

Answer (score 0):

My friend David Jones (Microsoft MVP on embedded) wrote some article on mimic web portal on Windows IoT Core with all its features.
I think you can find something useful here :

http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones